# Internal Links removed after splitting pdf into single pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf

I am splitting the pdf using pdfsam into single pages.After splitting all the internal links are removed.Is there any way to access the internal links between pages in the pdf ? but i can able to access the website links

how the internal links i.e page number are stored inside the annots array. i cant able to get the page number in goto

Comment: how are you using pdfsam on the iphone? its a java thing i believe?

Comment: no m not using that in iphone i have splitted the pdf using that one in mac

Comment: Web links work fine because they are still valid after being split (the URL is still valid). The problem is that "internal" link annotations are usually associated with a Go-To Action and/or a Destination (esplicit or named) that are not valid anymore. I suppose that replacing the link's Go-To Action with a Remote Go-To Action would alleviate the issue, but I don't think that pdfsam can do this and thus should be performed manually. PDF Reference 1.7, chapter 8.4 (Annotations), especially Link Annotation and chapters 8.2.1 (Destinations) and 8.5 (Actions) will make a lot of things clear.

Comment: Thanks sigsegv i have one more doubt i am using voyeur to see the internal structure of the PDF file.  If i saw the complete PDF file using that before splitting means it has a Dicitonary D inside the Annots Array which contains 5 values page object (Dictionary) , FitR , destination rect (x1,y1,x2,y2) how to get the page number from that page object.

Answer (score 3):

I think this code help out you
https://github.com/vfr/Reader